# PowerBI calculated column to convert a string to a sortable value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, daxstudio

I'm trying to "order" a group of date bands for an AR aging project in a PowerBI matrix visual.  By creating a calculated column and have successfully used this format in the past.

```
Month Name = SWITCH('3CashAgingAnalysis'[Financial Period],1,"January",2,"February",3,"March",4,"April",5,"May",6,"June",7,"July",8,"August",9,"September",10,"October",11,"November",12,"December")
```

This format  works for me...

```
AgeBandIndex = SWITCH('12ARAgingAll(T)'[AgeBand],"0 - 30",1,"31 - 60",2,"61 - 90",3,"91 - 120",4,"121 - 150",5,"151 - 180",6," > 180",7)
```

I'd like to get a table column to "sort" (PowerBI > Comunm tools> Sort by column) when finished like

| date band | index |
| --- | --- |
| 0 - 30 | 1 |
| 31 - 60 | 2 |
| 61 - 90 | 3 |
| 91 - 120 | 4 |
| 121 - 150 | 5 |
| 150 - 180 | 6 |

I have two questions, please

- is this the "enlightened" way to accomplish this?

or

- is there a better way using time intelligence?

Comment: This is a good approach.

Comment: If you have a start date and a current date, then you could dynamically calculate your date band, since in your case the increments are all equal.  Something like Round (Divide (CurrentDate-StartDate), 30,0,0).